# PDFBox Page 1 nullpointer

Tags: java, pdfbox

im trying to get the first and last page label of my pdf file.
but im currently having an issue when accessing a PDF File that starts with a page label of "1" it always returns a null pointer exception

```
pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfFilePath);
        pageLabels = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPageLabels();

        pdfl = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPageLabels();
setfPage(Double.parseDouble(pdfl.getLabelsByPageIndices()[0]));
setlPage(Double.parseDouble(pdfl.getLabelsByPageIndices()pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages() - 1]));
```

it works fine on other pdf files that doesn't start with "1" as page label.

Comment: store the value of `pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages()` in a variable and try to debug the code to look what it return.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap yes i did that by doing, System.out.println(pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages());... it returns the correct number of pages.

Comment: which line gives you null pointer ? please check your line number in stackTrace.

Comment: i did a work around where i manually set the page numbering style of the 1st page to NONE, and just manually set the fpage as 1.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap this line gives the null pointer setfPage(Double.parseDouble(pdfl.getLabelsByPageIndices()[0]));

Comment: it means `pdfl.getLabelsByPageIndices()` method reflects a null as a String Array `String[]`.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap i know, but it shouldn't i defined the page labels correctly, but when i change the 1st page numbering style to NONE, it gives me an Array String[] but the index 0 is empty, thats why i just manually set its value to 1.